# Only keep rows with first occurence Power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table with ID's and Dates, however some ID's have multiple Dates, and I only want to keep the earliest date, so the ID's don't appear multiple times in the table.
Dates are Day/Month/Year.

Example:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| ID 1 | 1/4/2022 |
| ID 2 | 1/6/2022 |
| ID 3 | 12/20/2021 |
| ID 3 | 4/5/2022 |
| ID 3 | 24/7/2022 |
| ID 4 | 3/1/2022 |
| ID 4 | 3/5/2022 |
| ID 5 | 15/8/2022 |

What I want to happen:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| ID 1 | 1/4/2022 |
| ID 2 | 1/6/2022 |
| ID 3 | 12/20/2021 |
| ID 4 | 3/1/2022 |
| ID 5 | 15/8/2022 |

So basically I want to remove duplicate rows based on ID and keep the one with the earliest date.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like you have a mix of euro and US dates.

I've gone and assumed **12/20/2021** (ID 3) is due to a typo and made it **12/02/2021**, as all other dates fit in the european date format.

[screenshot of initial data, date formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEgYs.png)

To answer your question, you can use the **Group By** function:

1. Go to **Transform** > **Group By**
2. Select **Basic** (you only have one column)
3. Select **ID** from drop-down list (that will be the column you will group by)
4. Create your new column, named something like Earliest Date, select **Operation Min**, and choose the **Date** column from the last drop-down list.

Essentially what this does is group your table by ID (hence removing duplicate IDs), and returning the minimum of your Date column.

[Using Group By](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7M7N.png)

[You should end up with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/259Gu.png)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion with the date format, I indeed made a mistake typing it over. This did however work like a charm for me, thank you very much for the in-dept explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your dates seem like a mixture of locales BTW and will need to be fixed. For this specific problem:

1. Sort ID ascending. Sort Date ascending.
2. Highlight ID column and select remove duplicates from the ribbon.

[image]